# how to use virtualbox network printer

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using ubuntu 15.10 32-bit, I installed virtualbox with win 7 guest. I'm trying to print on guest machine using network printer, but it doesn't work for me.

first how to know the default gate away to use on printer address

second when i set up the network setting for virualbox, I enable network adapter attached to bridge adapter, but there is no eth0, it gives me wlp6s0

[image]